# How to make a script run after api fetch (the <script> html element)? React + Adobe Acrobat Sign integration

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, acrobat

I'm trying to add an Adobe Acrobat Sign widget to a react page, passing the script inside jsx. But it does not run. How can I make it run when the element is rerendered?

```
  {consentFormStore.selectedFormData?.widgetId ? (
    <>
      <script defer>console.log("foo")</script>
      <script
        type="text/javascript"
        defer
        src={`h

ttps://secure.na3.adobesign.com/public/embeddedWidget?wid=${consentFormStore.selectedFormData?.widgetId}`}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Typography>Something went wrong creating the document</Typography>
      )}
```

"foo" is never printed, and the form for signing never appears. Creating a raw html with the script, It is possible to see the effect of script execution

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding `<script>` tag directly in jsx, try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (consentFormStore.selectedFormData?.widgetId) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https:..`;
      script.async = true;
      script.onload = () => console.log('foo');
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  }, [consentFormStore.selectedFormData?.widgetId]);
```

Comment: this makes the console.log run, but the script itself is not ran, it is just added to the DOM